# How to select elements from a list using another list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and would like to display all `list1` elements which have the common `list2` element - in this case it is `'a'`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c']
```

Expected result:

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed only one common element in `list2`?

Comment: I retrieved two columns from a csv and I have created two different lists. Two columns are Countries and Products respectively.

Countries -> USA, Canada, Brazil, China, Japan
Products -> Apple, Apple, Orange, Grapes, Apple.

Expected Output -> USA, Canada and Japan (List countries which has the product Apple).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `compress`:

```
from itertools import compress

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5] 
list2 = ['a','b','a','a','c']

element = 'a'

selectors = [i == element for i in list2]
result = list(compress(list1, selectors))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

input

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
l2 = ['a','b','a','c','e','a','e','f']
```

If you know a is your object(the element have at least one duplicate), then

```
ans = []
for i in range(len(l2)):
    if l2[i] == 'a':
        ans.append(l1[i])
print(ans)
```

otherwise

```
ans2 = []
charDict = {}
for i in range(len(l2)):
    if l2[i] not in charDict:
        charDict[l2[i]] = []
    charDict[l2[i]].append(l1[i])
for key in charDict:
    if len(charDict[key]) > 1:
        print(charDict[key])
```

if more than 1 character have duplicate, code above will print all of them

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
from collections import Counter
list1= [1,2,3,4,5] 
list2 = ['a','b','a','a','c']
count = Counter(list2)
most_common_char = count.most_common()[0][0]
print([list1[idx] for idx in range(len(list2)) if list2[idx] == most_common_char])
# Prints [1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declaration of the list is incorrect. No need to mention **list**

   > lst1= [1,2,3,4]
2. Elements in the second list are incorrectly used. 
   Please understand that a,b,c,... are characters and must be in the inverted commas.

   So, you must declare the second list as:

   > lst2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
3. Each element in the list has a index number. The first elements has the index number 0 and it increases by 1 for the following elements in the list.

   For e.g. in the list ['a','b', 'c']

   > 'a' has index number 0
   >
   > 'b' has index number 1
   >
   > 'c' has index number 2
4. Now, you have to find the duplicate elements and also the position of it. 
   Make another list to store unique numbers, i.e. the list will not contain the duplicate numbers. Now, pick one element from this list and using loop on lst2, find the duplicates using if-else condition. If you find the duplicate, print the location using:

   > lst2.index(element) +1 
   >   (increment because the indexing starts from 0)